# Reload window on every jasmine spec in teaspoon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, teaspoon

Using teaspoon and jasmine to test some JS. The js is putting things in 'window'.

Is there a way to completely reload the page for every spec so that this 'window' is newly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if reloading the browser will be a good idea. You could run into `Some of your tests did a full page reload` jasmine error and it could make your tests slow. What I would do is take advantage of the `beforeEach`, `beforeAll`, `afterEach`, `afterAll` hooks.

`beforeEach` runs before every `it` test in a `describe` block and `beforeAll` runs once before all of the `it` tests inside of a `describe` block.

`afterEach` runs after every `it` tests in a `describe` block and `afterAll` runs once after all of the `it` tests inside of a `describe` block.

What you can do is take advantage of these hooks and appropriately add and remove stuff to the window and do clean up after each test (in maybe `afterEach` or `afterAll`) hooks.

Comment: it is not me that is adding. The page is loaded. A button is shown. A js library attaches itself to the button. This js library is gcc compiled and we have not access to any of its api. This library is ours library. It attaches itself to document ready. And when the button is pressed it puts stuff in window. On the next test we are still in the same window. We can not call anything in beforeAll and beforeEach. Actually it is a bit more difficult because it also loads other things, etc, etc, so I am simplifying. I just need to load the document again for this specific test.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but somewhere in `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` put a handle to a variable called `oldWindow = window;` where `oldWindow` will be the `window` without properties added. Then after the properties are added, you can maybe do `window = oldWindow;` to remove them. Maybe you have to do it the `Object.assign` way, but something like this.

Comment: but document on ready is called before beforeAll, and beforeEach and I can not take a reference to the old window.